# force to download images using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, download

I want force to download image instead of opening in the browser. I tried with the following code with php

```
//set the content as octet-stream     
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");    // 
// tell the thing the filesize 
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($download_path.$file));     
// set it as an attachment and give a file name 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file); 
// read into the buffer 
readfile($download_path.$file);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the below line in .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:jpg|gif|png)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```